# How to match entries that have commas?

Tags: php, validation

In a table I have a field that stores users who are allowed to see a post.  I have something like `93849038,39480398` where the commas separates the users.

So this is what I am trying to do:

```
$user = logged in user; example: 93849038.
```

And this is what my query looks like:

```
 $sql = "SELECT note FROM notes_are WHERE user_allowed = '$user' ORDER 
 BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
```

Using a structure like that I am unable to serve the post.

Comment: That's a very poorly-designed table.

Comment: What you're doing is wrong. You need to stop using a concatenated list of IDs and start using real foreign keys. It is a terrible, awful thing to do to a database, and it will cripple your application.

Comment: That is a bad way to design your dB table, you do something along the lines of a row for each user that can see a specific post.

Comment: @meager so for each person that can see put them in a new row? I thought of doing that but thought of trying something like this first.

Comment: It's not about PHP, it's about database design. If you want to link a post to one or more users, and a user to one or more posts, you're talking about a ["many-to-many"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship, and you should implement it via a ["junction" or "join" table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a recommended practice as it forces the database engine to inspect all rows of your table. It's better to create a permission table where each user that has access to a note are listed separately (make sure to also index the user column).

If you really REALLY have to, you can use the `LOCATE` string function (assuming MySQL): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

Of course, `LOCATE` has issues too because it doesn't care about comma delimited stuff, so the "better" approach might be `REGEXP`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp